# Is it possible to setup and use 2 different security-settings.xml on the same machine?

Tags: xml, maven, build, nexus

In our company we are sharing the same build machine, but the projects use different Nexus Repository. So, we need to have different `settings-security.xml` files for each server (having different passwords).
I've placed one `settings-security.xml` in the `.m2` folder and run the build normally(working fine this one).

For the second build I've placed the `settings-security.xml` in the `\.m2\myproject\` folder and then ran the build like this:

```
mvn -s %USERPROFILE%\.m2\settings_myproject.xml -Dsettings.security=%USERPROFILE%\.m2\myproject\security-settings.xml clean install
```

But it's not working. I think that the default `settings-security.xml` from `\.m2\`
is used not the one I've specified in the build command.
I get following error message:

> [ERROR] Could not transfer artifact: Not authorized ,
>   ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]

So, do you know how can I use 2 different `settings-security.xml` on the same machine?

Thanks!

Comment: the first thing which I see as wrong having two different Nexus repositories cause   the groupId/artifactId is enough separation between projects. furthermore I recommend to use a CI solution like Jenkins which can handle such things...

Comment: We are running the builds from Jenkins...I forgot to mention :(

Comment: If you run already Jenkins than use the config file provider plugin which supports configuration a `settings.xml` with encryption inside jenkins and correct replacement of credentials. No need for manual / hand configurated `settings-security.xml`...